# Get-ComplianceSearch: 400 Bad Request with CBA authentication

Tags: powershell, o365security-compliance

As a part of RPS deprecation, I am trying to change my powershell script to use CBA authentication and followed the steps as mentioned in the documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps

I can able to create & start search. But I can't get the Search information via command.
Get-ComplianceSearch -Identity

But when I login with Interactive user login, everything works fine.

Verified the Fiddler trace and I can able to see the Mailbox anchor header alone different based on user account. Is there any other permission steps missing over there in the document.

1. Created app and assigned the permissions and generated the certificate.
2. Even I have provided compliance admin roles and then created service principle and added ediscoverymanager role. Nothing works.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/troubleshoot-authentication-access-control/